# How to fix blank youtube titles on chrome?

Tags: caching

I really hate to waste people's times with questions like this, so I would appreciate if any of you could help.

-About a week ago, I installed this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cache-killer/jpfbieopdmepaolggioebjmedmclkbap?utm_source=chrome-app-launcher-info-dialog because I'm a web developer and I needed to clear cache every so often (although I have disabled cache when the developer's console is open).

-Since then, youtube started to show blank titles and blank search terms on auto-suggestions suggestions.

screenshot1:
[image]

screenshot2:
[image]

Seems like some issue with youtube cached content. I know Google Chrome has an option to "Reset Browser" but I don't want to use it since it would clear up everything and reset all default settings. I have quite a lot of customizations so wouldn't want to loose them - or to go through the hassle of backup/restore.

I was wondering if any of you ever had a similar issue that could suggest how to fix it?

Thanks for your time :)

Comment: Did you try removing the extension?

Comment: I would try removing the extension like TimoSta suggested and see if that fixes the problem, which I'm guess it will. If it does, I'd recommend contacting the developer for assistance or using an alternative extension that offers the same functionality.

Comment: @TimoSta +Dillan I had disabled the extension earlier, but I just uninstalled it as you suggested. The problem is still the same, uninstallation didn't fix anything.

Comment: Hm.. Does the same thing happen when you open an incognito window?

Comment: yep, the same exact problem even when I open a new incognito window.

Comment: Try disabling the rest of your extensions to see if any of the others could be causing the problem

Comment: Just disabled all extensions, cleared cache manually, restarted the browser two times; the same problem happens - no hope yet :)

Comment: Well. I'm out of ideas \_(ツ)_/ lol

Comment: okay, thanks for your time Dillan. If I find a workaround to this, will post it here for others.

Comment: **UPDATE:**

Looks like the problem is not with Google Chrome only. The problem with blank titles on youtube happens with Opera browser also.

Youtube works correctly on Safari browser and on Firefox though.

So apparently it seems like a problem with the chrome engine or something related. I'm looking into that.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing roboto fonts, it helped me. Link is http://developer.android.com/design/style/typography.html

Comment: I had Roboto font installed already. Just installed it again, but no luck. Doesn't seem a font issue to me though.